# How do I apply border bottom to more than one line of text?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm using border-bottom for all the CATs on my website. Great when it a word or two. On trying to apply it to a CTA that's more than a sentence, the words break on mobile and the border-bottom only affects the last line of the sentence. How do I make the border-bottom affect the lines of text? I don't want to use underline for the sake of transition on hover, and the fact that underlines does not give my the 1px border I want.

See images for desktop, mobile and tab [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj28t.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me!

```css
.underline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline">Read more on research, empathy and personas on Medium</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

That transition may be applied on the pseudo element  ::before or ::after that is not underline for text.

```css
div
{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an</div>
```

underline for all words... hope this works

Comment: Thanks, Chandra but this is not what I want. The border-bottom I'm talking about is actually on a "::before" element. I did that for 2 reasons: I want a transition on hover; meaning the line transforms from 100% width to 0; And secondly, I wanted a 1px line which is part of my brand identity. Underline looks like a 2px border.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```css
div
{
display:inline;
border-bottom: solid 1px #000
}
```

```html
<div>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
</div>
```